# Blazor and protobuf-net doesn't compile in Release

Tags: protobuf-net

If you add the protobuf-net nuget package to a Blazor WASM app and compile in **Debug** everything works fine.

If you switch to **Release** VS says:

> Unhandled exception. Mono.Linker.LoadException: Error while processing
>   references of 'protobuf-net, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this type of error means that you need to configure the linker to not strip assemblies that are reflection-heavy; I would *guess* that this starts with:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <BlazorLinkerDescriptor Include="LinkerConfig.xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

in the csproj, and a `LinkerConfig.xml` file that contains (at least):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<linker>
  <assembly fullname="protobuf-net" />
</linker>
```

Note that I'm also working on AOT / pre-gen options for protobuf-net (using protobuf-net.Core in v3, which does not have any of the reflection code), which would be the *ideal* scenario here; but that is at least a couple of months out.

Comment: Thanks Marc for the answer and mostly for protobuf-net, it's great. Unfortunately this doesn't work, I added the tag in the csproj and the file but nothing changed and honestly I can't follow you on the subject so maybe my fault, I'm missing something.

Comment: @Pietro I would have to look; I don't have an immediate answer here, as I'm not a blazor person (they don't let me near the UI much... not since "that one time")

Comment: Just to let you know that I tried to install 3.0.0-alpha.155 and this works fine, I can compile in release. Now the decision to take is: publish the app with 2.4 in Debug or with 3.0 in Release? ;)

Comment: @Pietro I haven't announced this yet, because of release notes etc, but: https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/3.0.0